# "Setter" for a list

Tags: spring-boot, xsd

To the [countries](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) web service, I added new complexType "writer":

```
<xs:complexType name="country">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
         ...
        <xs:element name="writer" type="tns:writer" maxOccurs="unbounded"    />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType  name="writer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="surname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I would like to be able to add multiple writers

In generated Country class writer list is protected and there is no setter for this list:

```
public class Country {

    ...
    protected List<Writer> writer;

    ...

    public List<Writer> getWriter() {
        if (writer == null) {
            writer = new ArrayList<Writer>();
        }
        return this.writer;
    }

}
```

How can I add writer to country then?

I cannot access writer list like that:

```
        Writer w = new Writer();
        w.setName("Miguel");
        w.setSurname("Cervantes");

        Country spain = new Country();
        spain.setName("Spain");
        spain.writer.add(w);
```

It throws error:

```
writer has protected access in io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service.Country
```

Comment: `spain.getWriter().add(w);`?

Comment: yes it works, thanx